# MacBook Air M1 で Laravel が動作しない

Tags: php, macos, laravel

一度動かせたはずのLaravelが、`php artisan serve` をしても効かなくなりました。
Macbookair M1でlaravelの環境構築を完了させ、使える状態にしたいです。

#### 今の状況

1. `cd laravelapp` として、`ユーザー名MacBook-Air laravelapp %` が返ってくるのでディレクトリは作れてると思います。
2. `php artisan serve` が効かないです（Could not open input file: artisan とエラーが表示される）
   デスクトップのlaravelappの直下にartisanファイルがあることは確認しています。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: laravelディレクトリ中で`composer install`してから、`php artisan serve`をしてみてください。

Comment: Nichoさん、ありがとうございます！！
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/ユーザー名/laravelapp
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
とエラーが表示されます。まだ自分の方でエラーの解析が済んでないので、これから解析しようと思います。

Comment: cubickさんも、僕の質問文を校正してくださりありがとうございます。
直接お礼を言うやり方がわからないのでこの場でお礼申し上げます